# Using if-not paths and dynamically modify styles together plone.app.theming

Tags: plone, diazo

I am trying to dynamically change the style on every page *but the front page* of Plone using plone.app.theming (diazo).

So far I have cobbled together this but it breaks my theme:

```
<replace css:content="#some-div" if-path="not(body.section-front-page)"
<style type="text/css">
#some-div { margin: 0 2.25em }
</style>
</replace>
```

Any help on how to write a combined if-not path and dynamically modifying styles would be appreciated!
Added the missing closing tag, still does not work.

Comment: It appears that you missed the closing ")" in your condition. Is this also in your rules.xml or it's just a copy/paste error? Plus, are you sure of using a replace for "#content"? It will replace the dom element with id=content with this tag..this doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

for me it looks like there are several errors in your rules.xml file.

a) replace requires a content and theme attribute.
see http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/basic.html#replace

b) you normally do not put css into your rules.xml file. and the way it's inserted above won't work

c) the if-path condition works on parts of the url. and you are testing for a certain class of the body.
you'd rather go for one of those

```
if-path="/front-page" 
if-content="body.section-front-page"
```

(see http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/advanced.html#conditions-based-on-paths)

the best starting point is to skim through the documentation
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming

download one of the diazo themes on plone.org as a template
http://plone.org/products?getCategories=themes&getCompatibility=Plone+4.1&SearchableText=diazo

and look up the different rules on http://docs.diazo.org

Comment: I was hoping someone would write the code for me, since I cannot seem to to do. You say "you normally do not put css into your rules xml" Then why does Diazo have this on their site? 

Modifying the theme on the fly

Diazo allows you to modify the theme using “inline” markup in the rules file. You can think of this as a rule where the matched content is explicitly stated in the rules file, rather than pulled from the response being styled.

<after theme-children="/html/head">
    <style type="text/css">
        /* From the rules */
        body > h1 { color: red; }
    </style>
</after>

Comment: Diazo lets you use CSS *selectors* to choose which blocks of HTML to manipulate, but a Diazo rules file is not where you do the actual styling of HTML with CSS, that is still done in CSS as normal.  You may want to read the Diazo docs a bit more closely to understand the idea of how Diazo is about transforming HTML between Plone's template output and your own custom HTML templates.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I have all of my styles in a css file. I am not putting any styles *except one* in the rules file. I am doing this because I want to change the previous style for that div (specified in the css) dynamically on the fly on one page only. In other words, for that one div on that one page, I want the style to change, but on all other pages the div takes the style from the css file. I need to know how to write that in the rules.xml for special cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Diazo is the right tool to solve this problem, try the following CSS:

```
#some-div { margin: 0 2.25em }
body.section-front-page #some-div { margin: 0 }
```

The nice thing about Plone's section css classes is that it allows you to write a single CSS file for your entire site while still targeting rules at specific sections.

Comment: That option no longer exists in Plone 4, unfortunately, which is why I am trying the rules approach.

Comment: The css class is still set on the body in Plone 4. Could you be more specific about which/how the option is no longer available?

Comment: getsectionURL isn't that what you meant. .section is used for that. I am trying to do this in the rules.xml not the getsectionURL method. It's depreciated in Plone 4.

Comment: getSectionURL was replaced by the ``bodyClass()`` method of the plone_layout view, but setting a body class (including the section- class) is still very much supported. The if-path stuff in diazo is mainly there for other system which do not have an equivalent to Plone's body classes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your front page is a Document with the 'front-page' id, then you can do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css">

  <rules css:if-content="body.section-front-page.template-document_view)">
  <!-- here you put rules for the front page only -->
  </rules>

  <rules css:if-content="body:not(.section-front-page.template-document_view)">
    <after css:content-children="head">
      <style>
      #some-div { margin: 0 2.25em; }
      </style>
    </after>
  </rules>

</rules>
```

Specifying the .template-document_view helps you not to scramble with @@manage-portlets screen at home, for instance.